# Please tell me how to code this problem in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Q. It takes a number until 0 is entered and stores the number as a list
    Write a program that stores and prints the sorted odd and even numbers as the final list.

Input example 1

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
0
```

Output example 1

```
[1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6]
```

Input example 2

```
12
68
49
13
46
2
6
7
2
1
3
97
67
45
0
```

Output example 2

```
[1, 3, 7, 13, 45, 49, 67, 97, 2, 2, 6, 12, 46, 68]
```

Please tell me how to code this problem in python3....

```
n = int(input())
s = []
```

and... 
I can't figure out how to write code after this.

Comment: Can you show what you did? What are your specific questions about how to code this solution?

Comment: n = int(input()) s = []  and ..... 
I can't figure out how to write code after this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
inputlist = [2, 34, 66, 1, 2, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

So using sorted and list addition:

```
sorted([i for i in inputlist if i%2 == 1]) + sorted([i for i in inputlist if i%2 == 0])
```

gives:

```
[1, 7, 9, 2, 2, 8, 10, 34, 66]
```

---

Explanation:

- `[i for i in inputlist if i%2 == 1]` gives all the odd numbers in the `inputlist`, and using `sorted()`, the values are arranged.
- `[i for i in inputlist if i%2 == 0]` gives all the even numbers in the `inputlist`, and using `sorted()`, the values are arranged.

---

A code with input:

```
inputlist = []
while True:
    a = int(input("Enter the number:"))
    if a:
        inputlist.append(a)
    else:
        break
result = sorted([i for i in inputlist if i%2 == 1]) + sorted([i for i in inputlist if i%2 == 0])
```

Comment: Thank you for answer
But I am still not sure how to write the whole code. Can I know the whole code?

Comment: Thanks!! :) 
I have adopted your answer